# Impossible to display data asynchronously with nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm working a static vue website fetching data with the wordpress rest api.

I'm trying to display the data I fetch on a API on the vue page :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>
          {{ title }}
        </h1>
        <template>
          {{ content }}
        </template>
        <p><nuxt-link to="/">Back to home page</nuxt-link></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  validate({ params }) {
    return isNaN(+params.slug)
  },
  asyncData({ params, error }) {
    let slug = params.slug;
    // We can return a Promise instead of calling the callback
    return axios.get('https://dev.lesdeuxvagues.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug='+slug)
      .then((res) => {
        return { data: res.data }
      })
  },
}

</script>
```

I also tried this way :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <h1>
          {{ title }}
        </h1>
        <template>
          {{ content }}
        </template>
        <p><nuxt-link to="/">Back to home page</nuxt-link></p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'
export default {
  validate({ params }) {
    return isNaN(+params.slug)
  },
  async asyncData({ params, error }) {
    try {
      let slug = params.slug;
      const { data } = await axios.get(`https://dev.lesdeuxvagues.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/?slug=`+slug)
      return data
    } catch (e) {
      error({ message: 'Article not found', statusCode: 404 })
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

but neither of the two solutions work...

I think the problem is coming from the async function, but I didn't get why..

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Your results come back as an array of objects and not an object. Depending on which method you're using above you can try `return data[0]` or `return { data: res.data[0] }`. If you receive more than 1 object back in the array I'd iterate over the data array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what you may want to try. Of course, you can customize your API with your convenience.

```
<template>
    <p>
        {{data}}
    </p>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {

    asyncData(context) {
        // We can return a Promise instead of calling the callback
        return axios.get('https://dev.lesdeuxvagues.com/api/wp-json/wp/v2/posts/')
            .then((res) => {
                return {
                    data: res.data[0]
                }
            })
    },
}

</script>
```